# Count amount of words that are specific length

Tags: vba, excel, google-sheets, formula

Im trying to count amount of words in a cell that are larger or equal to 3 characters.

I've got the simple "counta" working, which is

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2);0;LEN(TRIM(D2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;" ";""))+1)
```

or

```
=IF(LEN(D2)=0;0;COUNTA(SPLIT(D2;" "))
```

)

I know that in regex it would be something simple like this

```
"\w{3,}"
```

But I can't come up with a solution to only count the words that are specific length in Sheet syntax.
Can someone help me with that, or at least guide me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a shorter formula, but this works in Sheets.

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(SPLIT(D2, " "), LEN(SPLIT(D2, " "))>=3)))
```

Comment: That's so simple, and it works! Thank you, I couldn't come up on how to incorporate a filter in there (never used SPLIT or LEN before today)

Any chance you could recommend something to read about Google Sheets formula's?  The defaults google wiki is good if you want to know about a certain function, rather than a few of them jammed together

Comment: Found this guy on Stack Overflow. Lots to pick up on from his blog. https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ARRAYFORMULA(len(SPLIT(D2," "))>=3))
```